# Doesn't go to the right frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have three frames. The first frame is the original. When the marker hits the right answer (target i should say), it must proceed to frame 3. If the answer is wrong it should go to frame 2. But the things when the marker hits the right answer the frame that is being shown is frame 2 and not frame 3. Why is that so?

```
marker._x = 93.0;
marker._y = 62.0;
status.text = "ANSWER"

marker.onPress = function() 
{
    this.startDrag();
}
marker.onRelease = marker.onReleaseOutside = function()
{
    this.stopDrag();
    if(eval(this._droptarget)==A)
    {
        this._x = A._x;
        this._y = A._y;
        status.text = "CORRECT";

        gotoAndPlay("3");

    }
    else if(eval(this._droptarget)==B)
    {
        this._x = B._x;
        this._y = B._y;
        status.text = "WRONG";

        gotoAndPlay("2");

    }
    else if(eval(this._droptarget)==C)
    {
        this._x = C._x;
        this._y = C._y;
        status.text = "WRONG";
        gotoAndPlay("2");
    }
    else if(eval(this._droptarget)==D)
    {
        this._x = D._x;
        this._y = D._y;
        status.text = "WRONG";
        gotoAndPlay("2");
    }
    else
    {
marker._x = 93.0;
marker._y = 62.0;
    status.text = ""
    }

}
```

Comment: This is clearly not AS3.  Retagging it as AS2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from your `gotoAndPlay()` statements.

If you are jumping to a frame number, it should be `gotoAndPlay (2);`, for example.  You should use String values only for jumping to labelled frames, but label names should not be number characters.

Also, make sure you have a `stop()` somewhere, so that the movie will not just flash and pass over the frame you want to jump to.  You could also use `gotoAndStop();`, by the way.